# Rabbit MQ doesn't flush acks?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

The problem appeared in logs: `Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?`

We try to open handlers for like 50 queues dynamically by `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.addQueueNames()`, then application is started. It consumes some messages, but the RabbitMQ admin panel shows that they are unacked. After a significant amount of time, messages are stacking up to 6 unacked messages (queue has fairly low amount of messages per minute) per queue, which sums up to 300 messages total, something happens and they all become consumed and acked. While messages are unacked, the container seems to be trying to load another consumer until it bumps into the limit.

We rely on `AUTO` acknowledgment mode now, when it was `MANUAL`, it was fine.

There are two questions:

1. What can be the reason for unacked messages? Is there any flushing mechanism that doesn't trigger often?
2. What do I do with "not enough threads" message?

Those two seem to be really related one to another.

Here's the setup:

```java
@Bean
fun queueMessageListenerContainer(
    connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
    retryOperationsInterceptor: RetryOperationsInterceptor,
    vehicleQueueListenerFactory: QueueListenerFactory,
): SimpleMessageListenerContainer {
    return SimpleMessageListenerContainer().also {
        it.connectionFactory = connectionFactory
        it.setConsumerTagStrategy { queueName -> consumerTag(queueName) }
        it.setMessageListener(vehicleQueueListenerFactory.create())
        it.setConcurrentConsumers(2)
        it.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5)
        it.setListenerId("queue-consumer")
        it.setAdviceChain(retryOperationsInterceptor)
        it.setRecoveryInterval(RABBIT_HEARTH_BEAT.toMillis())
        //had 10-100 threads, didn't help
        it.setTaskExecutor(rabbitConsumersExecutorService)
        // AUTO suppose to set ack for the messages, right?
        it.acknowledgeMode = AcknowledgeMode.AUTO
    }
}

@Bean
fun connectionFactory(rabbitProperties: RabbitProperties): AbstractConnectionFactory {
    val rabbitConnectionFactory = com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory().also { connectionFactory ->
        connectionFactory.isAutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
        connectionFactory.isTopologyRecoveryEnabled = true
        connectionFactory.networkRecoveryInterval = RABBIT_HEARTH_BEAT.toMillis()
        connectionFactory.requestedHeartbeat = RABBIT_HEARTH_BEAT.toSeconds().toInt()
        // was up to 100 connections, didn't help
        connectionFactory.setSharedExecutor(rabbitConnectionExecutorService)
        connectionFactory.host = rabbitProperties.host
        connectionFactory.port = rabbitProperties.port ?: connectionFactory.port
    }
    return CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory)
        .also {
            it.cacheMode = rabbitProperties.cache.connection.mode
            it.connectionCacheSize = rabbitProperties.cache.connection.size
            it.setConnectionNameStrategy { "simulation-gateway:${springProfiles.firstOrNull()}:event-consumer" }
        }
}

class QueueListenerFactory { 
  fun create(){
     return MessageListener {
        try {
            // no ack, rely on AUTO acknowledgement mode
            handle()
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            ...
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Having 50 queues with 10 concurrent consumers each, seems quite heavy to me (50*10=500). Would you be sure you need it? Would your system be able to handle it? Did you try to reduce this number?

Comment: @yoni oops, wrong numbers, thank you for noticing. It's actually 2 and 5 currently, I've tried to lower the minimum to 1, that didn't help. My assumption so far is that it tries to use more than 1 because of the unacked messages.

Comment: What version are you using? Also Spring AMQP does not support auto recovery in the amqp-client - it has had it's own recovery mechanisms that predate auto-recovery by many years. In most cases, problems like this is due to the consumer thread being "stuck" in user code; take a thread dump to see what the container threads are doing. The delay in staring might be due to somethhing else; the task executor problem is just the most likely; again, a thread dump should help.

Comment: @GaryRussell version is 2.2.17.RELEASE on release train of spring-boot 2.3.11.RELEASE. We have recovery like this because it can recover after losing connection to the rabbit because of the network problems. Would you recommend using another way? On the thread dump most of threads are stuck at `LockSupport.park...SynchronousQueue.take`, that seems like means they wait for the messages to arrive...

Comment: Yes, it will recover without thos settings, we have had connection recovery for over a decade. We effectively disable auto recovery by immediately closing a recovered connection. It caused all kinds of problems with dangling consumers that never consumed anything. We added that code back in 2018 and have not had any recovery problems since then. I don't see how it is possible to have un-ack'd messages with AUTO ack mode unless the consumer thread is stuck. You need to show much more information - thread dump, logs, screen shots etc.

Comment: @GaryRussell you was right, that was the executor problem! I used an unlimited one with one minimum thread, and it doesn't expand further, and it seems like it doesn't need to, and works perfectly with like 7 connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the problem was. Basically, it couldn't start all of the queues consumers in time, since it not only is slow process for too slow for SimpleMessageListenerContainer, but also we tried to `addQueueNames` one by one.

```
   userRepository.findAll()
        .map { user -> queueName(user) }
        .onEach { queueName ->
            simpleContainerListener.addQueueNames(queueName)
        }
```

But the following line of documentation for `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` remained unnoticed:

```
The existing consumers will be cancelled after they have processed any pre-fetched messages and new consumers will be created
```

Which means what actually happened is recreation of (1, 2, ... N) consumers. What made it even worse is that if the request comes from the API, we did exactly the same `simpleContainerListener.addQueueNames(queueName)` after handling the request, which recreated all of consumers after that.

Also, recreation of the consumers was the reason why `AUTO` acknowledgement didn't work: threads were hanging trying to build enough consumers before the timeout.

I fixed this by adding `DirectMessageListenerContainer` to handle recently added queues, which is blazing fast, compared to `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for the particular case of adding just one new consumer.

```
DirectMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory).also {
        it.setConsumerTagStrategy { queueName -> consumerTag(queueName, RECENT_CONSUMER_TAG) }
        it.setMessageListener(ListenerFactory.create())
        it.setListenerId("queue-consumer-recent")
        it.setAdviceChain(retryOperationsInterceptor)
        it.setTaskExecutor(recentQueuesTaskExecutor)
        it.acknowledgeMode = AcknowledgeMode.AUTO
    }
```

The downside is `DirectMessageListenerContainer` using 1 thread per queue on every instance. This is exactly why I didn't want to use it in the first place, but using both `DirectMessageListenerContainer` for recent and `SimpleContainerListener` for already existing queues significantly reduces amount of thread required to handle those queues. As far as I understand, an overwhelming usage of `DirectMessageListenerContainer` will lead to OOM eventually, so the next step can be to transfer queues from direct to simple container listener in batches.